# How to print CorePlot Graph

Tags: cocoa, calayer, core-plot

I'm trying to print an NSView which includes a couple coreplot piecharts among other items. However the piecharts do not appear.  I now understand that layer backed views do not print, but I'm having difficultly locating any examples where people circumvented this and printed coreplot graphs within a NSView.  What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it worked as soon as I have set-up the printRect like:

```
NSRect printRect = NSZeroRect;
printRect.size.width  = (printInfo.paperSize.width - printInfo.leftMargin - printInfo.rightMargin) * printInfo.scalingFactor;
printRect.size.height = (printInfo.paperSize.height - printInfo.topMargin - printInfo.bottomMargin) * printInfo.scalingFactor;

self.hostingView.printRect = printRect;     
op = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:self.hostingView printInfo:printInfo];
```

Note `self.hostingView`refers to the CorePlot hostingView.

Comment: Thanks, this gets me moving in the right direction, this works great if you just want to plot a single graph. But, I have a couple graphs within a NSView, plus additional items, so I would like print all the items as I have them laid out in the NSView.  But this certainly gets me started.

Comment: Just had to set the printRect property in each of the hostviews to [self view] frame]] and all works! Thanks Again!

Comment: Actually very easy: self.hostingView.printRect = self.hostingView.bounds